# Open Multiple IE windows at the same, get data from the windows and update in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have code which opens a link in IE, gets data and updates in Excel.

I run this daily for 4000 to 5000 rows. It navigates 5000 times in one window and gets the data.

Is there a way to open 5 to 10 windows and get the data and update in Excel? It could save plenty of time.

```vb
Sub Records()
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim a, b, c

Sheets("Data").Select
Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
With objIE
    .Visible = True
    For i = 2 To Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        a = UCase(Trim(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value)): b = Split(a, "-"): CID = b(0): TT = b(1): c = Split(CID, "V"): CN = c(0): PID = c(1)
        x = "https://abc/" & PID & "/47/billing/phonepayor.esp?CLAIMID=" & CN & "&TRANSFERTYPE=" & TT
        .Navigate x
        Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set y = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("readonlydisplaytable")(2).Cells
        Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value = y(19).innerText
        Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 3).Value = y(21).innerText
        Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 4).Value = y(7).innerText
        Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 5).Value = y(9).innerText
        Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 6).Value = y(5).innerText
    Next i
    .Quit
End With
MsgBox i - 1 & " Records are completed.", 64, "Automation"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Breaking up the spreadsheet and running the macro on serval different computers is your best bet. There is no benefit running multiple IE sessions on the same computer. The bottle neck is the Browser. I have not tried to see if running multiple virtual machines over comes this bottle neck.

Comment: Thanks josh, right now i am doing that kind of process only, thought there might be some other coding involved to do in a smart way.